# Internet connectivity test (VB.NET)

Tags: vb.net, powershell

```
[Activator]::CreateInstance([Type]::GetTypeFromCLSID([Guid]‘{DCB00C01-570F-    4A9B-8D69-199FDBA5723B}’)).IsConnectedToInternet
```

http://blogs.msdn.com/powershell/archive/2009/04/03/setting-network-location-to-private.aspx

I have found this PowerShell code from the above source and it works as expected, however
I would like to get it working in VB.NET to check Internet connectivity. Could one of the
experts assist please, as I have been unable manage it so far?

Comment: What have you tried so far? You need to show you have made some effort as people are unwilling to write it for you.

Comment: https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=test+internet+connection+vb oh look, code in the first item...

Answer (score 2):

This is a simple interface to the underlying wininet API.

```
Private Declare Function InternetGetConnectedState Lib "wininet.dll" _ 
                (ByRef lpdwFlags As Int32, ByVal dwReserved As Int32) As Boolean        
Public Shared Function IsConnectedToInternet( ) As Boolean
    Try
        Dim flags as Integer;
        return InternetGetConnectedState(flags, 0)
    Catch
        return False
    End Try
End Function
```

See [PInvoke.net](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/wininet/InternetGetConnectedState.html)

Comment: This I have tried, but cannot get a reference to IsConnectedToInternet. I know all about winininet, but I am only trying to conert this example. This is what I tried:              `Dim myGuid2 As New Guid("DCB00C01-570F-4A9B-8D69-199FDBA5723B")
        Dim myType2 As Type = Type.GetTypeFromCLSID(myGuid2)
        Dim xxx As NetworkInterface = Activator.CreateInstance(myType2)`